# Perturb $\tanh(c(x-x_0))$ or similar functions around $x\rightarrow x+\delta x$

Tags: taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

Given the perturbation $x\rightarrow x+\delta x$, how can the function
$$
\tanh[c(x-x_0)],
$$
$c$ and $x_0$ constant, be perturbed? I'd like to have a form like
$$
f(x)\rightarrow f(x)+g(\delta x)
$$
such that I have the different orders separated. But I am not certain how I can split $\tanh[c(x+\delta x-x_0)]$.

Is there a standard procedure? A Taylor expansion would not lead to separated terms, because all the $\delta x$ terms would have a factor depending on $x$ as well, e.g. in a somewhat simpler example:

$$
\exp(cx)\rightarrow\exp(cx)\exp(c\delta x)\approx\exp(cx)(1+c\delta x)
$$

for $\delta x$ small.

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the comments (thx!) a Taylor Series around $\delta x=0$ is the way to go and the result even have to depend on $x$, so therefore I expect that
$$
\tanh[c(x-x_0)]\rightarrow\tanh[c(x+\delta x-x_0)]\approx\tanh[c(x-x_0)]+\frac{c\delta x}{\cosh^2[c(x-x_0)]}
$$
is the way to go.

Comment: Do a Taylor series around $\delta x=0$. Your result must depend on $x$ though, different values $x$ will give different expansions.

Comment: There's no reason to expect the perturbation to be independent of $x$. Clearly as $x\to\pm\infty$, then $|f(x+\delta x)-f(x)|\to0$.

Comment: @David Thank you, I hope I did it correctly, but I added the Tayler series for both functions.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Good example, thx!